# RDBMS and Graph Database on the same Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm developing a web app that has several "subapps" inside it. For some of them a RDBMS is clearly the weapon of choice. The issue is that lately I came with an idea for a nice little subapp whose logic and performance would benefit greatly from using a graph based database.

My problem is: This subapp is important and graph is the way to make it happen. On the other hand, the others are just fine on a RDBMS and in some cases migrating them to graph would add unnecessary complexity.

So, is it possible to have two heterogeneous database systems running on the same Rails app, perhaps using each controller to specify where to connect?

Answer (score 2):

This is absolutely possible, but it's not something you'd handle at a controller level: it is the responsibility of each model class to define how its data is stored, for example by subclassing from `ActiveRecord::Base` or including `Mongoid::Document` or `Neo4j::ActiveNode`.

There's nothing particular you need to do. As long as the objects all conform to the active model interface (the above all do) then things like `link_to 'Person', @person` will still work.

Comment: Oh, at the model, of course! How fantastic! I will begin to fiddle with it right away. Thank you very much for your answer.